# Docs for harfbuzz-ng or API details

Tags: harfbuzz

I was working on harbuzz old one. now a new version of harbuzz-ng has came. now this structure is completely changes in comparison of old code. Without API docs its really hard to work/use this library. I google about it but didnot find any relavent details.

How can i start using it. Any test program to understand the input and output for this library.

If anybody have a test /hello world type from or any reference docs for API please share.

Answer (score 5):

Some good and simple examples are listed on [Harfbuzz wiki](https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/wiki#user-examples), [1](https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/blob/master/util/shape-consumer.hh), [2](https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/blob/master/util/view-cairo.hh)

I suggest you a higher level library, [Pango](http://www.pango.org/) if you need layout things like line wrap and I guess you would find better [doucmentation for it](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/) than HarfBuzz itself.

You may have a look at [State of Text Rendering](http://behdad.org/text/) also.

Answer (score 0):

- adding to the above examples i have also made and collected  some sample harfbuzz examples which you can find it [here](https://github.com/phunsukwangdu/python_pango/tree/master/harfbuzz_programs)
- this link https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/HarfBuzz-0.0/index.html might aid you
- I would say you should read all [Harfbuzz mail archives](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/harfbuzz/)
- plus go to harfbuzz github acc try reading pr and issues threads.
- at last due to scarcity of documentations,the only doc you got is the sourcecode itself :P